# What are the technology used to develop shopping apps like jabong, myntra, flipkart etc.?

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

What are the technology used to develop shopping apps like Jabong, Myntra, Flipkart etc. ? Can anyone provide more details or any link to know about hybrid app development. I am a beginner and i am unaware about hybrid app development technologies. I tried googling but could not find which is best, like phonegap etc. I don't know pros and cons of each one.  Pardon me if my question was found irrelevant, i need some expert comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: with the help of PhoneGap,Tamarin you can create Hybrid Applications.

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try http://phonegap.com/ this is a platform where you can develop hybrid apps using CSS, HTML5 etc . Take some time learning these technologies and see for yourself if it suits your need. Do not engage yourself learning how they did it, try to learn thing and see what is the best fit for the problem at hand. What worked for them may not work for you at all.

Comment: thank you sir, i am a beginer so i was not aware of this